# Android-Application Class act as singleton?

Tags: java, android, static, singleton, android-context

I have a class extending application and I am accessing it in other classes using its object like

```
private <class-name> <object-name>;
```

and initialising it like:

```
<object-name> =(<class-name> ) context.getApplicationContext();
```

Will it act as singleton or multiple instances will be formed?

if multiple instances are formed than how can I create to act it like singleton?

if it acts like a singleton, than I can access my static variables via it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes App is singleton. But for geting the instance of it try this:

```
public class App extends Application{   

private static App instance;

public static App getInstance() {
    return instance;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    instance = this;
    .....
}


}
```

Comment: Whats the prob with my approach ??

Comment: it is not good to cast something in your code: 
App myApp = (App)contect.getApplicationContext
and it is not so good becouse you are needed get "context" in every place where you want access to App. For example you want to get access to your App from some business logic you shoud pass refference to context to it.

in my case it is not necessary you just get instance App.getInstance() and use it like singleton

Comment: ok ...than singleton and this means same ...if u make fn like getinstance ()....?

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: my ques is ....if u make fn in app class <getinstace()> than isnt it similar to singletomn ?....why than extending application?

Comment: <object-name> =(<class-name> ) context.getApplicationContext();
getApplicationContext() is activity method. What if you want to get access to  Application not from activity but from another class in your business logic?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104774/discussion-between-developer-and-konstantin-volkov).